# Concatenar filas en una sola agregando espacios

Tags: sql-server

He estado buscando en internet pero no encuentro nada parecido. En una tabla en SQL tengo tres columnas, nombres, apellido paterno y apellido materno,¿ Cómo puedo unir las columnas en una nueva, las tres en una con sus espacios? tengo el siguiente código dónde  agregué espacio entre los registros.

```
select nombre+' '+apPaterno+' '+apMaterno
from dbo.Empleados
```

Comment: select CONCAT (nombre, ' ', apPaterno, ' ', apMaterno) from dbo.Empleados

Comment: Perdón escribí mal el procedimiento pero si me funciona

Comment: ¿Cómo puedo unir los campos en uno nuevo, los tres en uno con sus espacios?

Comment: ¿O sea, que no solo se trata de unirlos en la consulta?  Si no que quieres que a la tabla misma se le agregue una nueva columna?

Comment: Los tres campos que tengo nombres, ap.pat y ap.mat quiero unirlos en un nuevo campo (una nueva columna), pero éstos necesitan el espacio entre ellos, cómo puedo hacer todo ésto? No sé si me explique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes agregar una nueva columna virtual a la tabla que sea la combinación de las otras 3 de esta manera:

```
alter table dbo.empleados
add NombreCompleto as nombre + ' ' + apPaterno + ' ' + apMaterno;
```

Cuando hagas `select * from dbo.empleados` verás que allí está la nueva columna:
<kbd>[**Demo**](http://rextester.com/WXQV62192)</kbd>.

Referencia: [Especificar columnas calculadas en una tabla](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms188300.aspx).

También es posible agregar una nueva columna *"normal"* a la que luego le asignas el valor de la combinación de las otras 3 columnas. Pero si haces esto, a medida que modifiques los valores de las diferentes columnas, tendrías que manualmente seguir sincrónizando la nueva columna.  Por eso te sugiero esta forma donde la columna es virtual y siempre reflejará los datos correctos según los valores de las otras 3 columnas.

Nota adicional: si es posible que una de las 3 columnas contenga valores `null`, entonces puede que usar `CONCAT` sea mejor que el operador `+`. Tendrías que probar y ver como deseas manejar los valores `null` en esos casos.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo soy nuevo en ésto, me sirvió bastante

Answer (score 0):

Usa la función CONCAT la cual une aquello que le mandes como parámetro en una sola tabla, solamente hay que asignarle un alias con

```
AS unAlias
```

para que el campo no tenga su nombre por defecto el cual seria : (CONCAT(nombre, ' ', apPaterno,' ', apMaterno)):

Así es como quedaría tu query:

```
SELECT CONCAT(nombre, ' ', apPaterno,' ', apMaterno) AS NOMBRE FROM dbo.Empleados;
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT Nombre = CONCAT_WS(' ', nombre, apPaterno, apMaterno) AS NOMBRE FROM dbo.Empleados;

CONCAT_WS Es acrónimo de CONCATENATE WITH SEPARATOR, agregándo el separador sólo una vez, además a diferencia del operador "+" (concatenar para cadenas) si alguna de las partes es NULL el resultado no se convierte en null, es como si pusieras:

ISNULL(columna, '')

Comment: Tu respuesta es solo codigo. Por favor mira [answer]. Se pide que expliques que hace este código (mas alla que a ti vos te parezca obvio, puede que otro usuario no lo vea tan simple).